# Negating there exists-for all composite

Tags: logic, quantifiers

Suppose $P$ is a proposition statement about $p$ and $q$, and $Q$ is a statement about $r$. Consider:

- There is a prime number $p$ such that $P$ is true for all integers $q < 10$.
- $Q$ is false for all real numbers $r \leq 5$.

What are the respective negations for the above sentences?

My attempts:

- For all prime numbers $p$, there is an integer $q \geq 10$ for which $P$ is false.
- $Q$ is true if there exists a real number $r > 5$.

Are these negations correct? Also, is it allowed to move the "there exists" part before "$P$ is false" even though the original statement has the latter before? Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Is $P$ meant to depend on integers $p,q$?  If so, what might it mean to say that "$P$ is false for all real numbers $r≤5$"?

Comment: @lulu My bad! I've edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Those negations appear to have nothing to do with the original statement.  Just try the one for $Q$.

Comment: I didn't understand the question about moving the "there exists" part. Can you restate?

Comment: @frabala I meant the literal sequence in which the quantifiers occur... If the original statement follows "for all" and then "P is true" and then "there exists", does the negation have to be in the order "there exists", then "P is false" and then "for all"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it a bit ambiguous to say that $P$ states something about $p$ and $q$, yet not denote is as $P(p,q)$. Similarly, I'd find it clearer if $Q$ was written as $Q(r)$. But ok, you use natural language to do first-order logic, so such ambiguities are only natural! :P

To the point:

Assuming that $p$ and $q$ range over integers, for the first sentence, you're almost there! You only do not take into account the case where $p$ may not be prime:

- Either $p$ is not prime or (it is prime and) there is an integer $q \geq 10$ for which $P$ is false.

For the second sentence, assuming that $r$ ranges over reals, I'd say

- There is a real $r > 5$ for which $Q$ is true.

The problem with your formulation is that the $r$ in your sentence

> $Q$ is true if there exists a real number $r>5$

does not refer to the $r$ that $Q$ states something about, but refers to *some* real number for which we happen to use the same letter $r$ to name it.

Comment: I see! However, for the first one, if we're looking at both cases (i.e. $p$ is prime or not), why don't we have to look at the cases where $q$ is an integer and $q$ is not an integer?

Comment: @TRONIIX you have a point. That's why I state "Assuming that $p$ and $q$ range over integers [...]". You can reject this assumption and try to reformulate the negation of the sentence.

Comment: Just a note: Then, do you assume that $p$ and $q$ range over reals? Over complex numbers? You could even assume that $p$ and $q$ may not necessarily be numbers!